# how to detect li that has ul child

Tags: jquery

I am trying to detect `<li>` elements which have `<ul>` child.

This is what I tried, but it is not working:

```
$('ul.meta-menu li').each(function() {
    if ( $(this).has('ul') ) {
               addClass('par');
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you tried `$('ul.meta-menu li').has('ul')`?

Comment: +1 @tewathia: `has` doesn't return a boolean. So `$('ul.meta-menu li').has('ul').addClass('par')` should be enough. Make this an answer, and you'll have at least one upvote. )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('ul.meta-menu li').each(function() {
    if ($(this).find('ul').length){
        $(this).addClass('par');
    }
});
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/vThLm/)

Comment: works, I just deleted find.ul before addclass before I want to add class to li not ul.

Comment: @OliveraKovacevic class is added to `li` only. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

using `child selector`

```
$('ul.meta-menu li > ul').each(
  $(this).parent().addClass('par');
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$('ul.meta-menu li').has('ul').addClass('color');
```

OR

```
$('ul.meta-menu li ul').parent().addClass('bold');
```

Either would work.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/JsGJ2/)

Comment: +1, I'd suggest adding an explanation about `has` (it reduces a set of elements, doesn't just make a boolcheck like `.is` - apparently that confused the OP).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
    $('ul.meta-menu').find('ul').addClass('par');
});
```

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/dKVFL/)**

If you want to style only the parent `li` **[see this example](http://jsfiddle.net/wW5S5/5/)**